# No virtual method loadThumbnail() in class ContentResolver or its super classes

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-context, android-contentresolver

When I use **`public @NonNull Bitmap loadThumbnail(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull Size size,@Nullable CancellationSignal signal)`** method ,

it is always showing this error

```
2019-12-24 16:16:10.661 30299-30299/com.shaheen.filemanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shaheen.filemanager, PID: 30299
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method loadThumbnail(Landroid/net/Uri;Landroid/util/Size;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap; in class Landroid/content/ContentResolver; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.ContentResolver' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at com.shaheen.filemanager.activities.FileSelectActivity.onCreate(FileSelectActivity.kt:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7027)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Is there is any other way to solve this error ?

**My code looks like this :**

```
val bitmap = applicationContext.contentResolver.loadThumbnail(uri,Size(5,5),null)
thumbnail_image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
screenshot_image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Comment: This method was added in API 29 (Android 10.0). Most likely you're calling it on lower API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `loadThumbnail()` was only added in API level 29 that Android 10.0 so it won't work in lower versions.
However, you can use image loader libraries like picasso or glide with the `uri`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the context of activity or fragment instead of application context ?

Comment: strange , have you tried rebuilding or invalidate cache and restart

Comment: have you tried to use alternative libraries like glide for instance , which is image loading library for android ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204787/discussion-between-shaheen-ahamed-s-and-talha-ahmed).